# How to scrape PDF files from a webpage if button sends a post request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wanted to scrape some pdfs from a website: https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/view-decision?commissionname=302&file_category=1&fileno=&name=&public_authority=&decisiontypeid=1&frdate=&todate=&page_length=10&search_button=Submit

But what I encountered is, the buttons to the pdfs are actually POST request which has some kind of unique token as a value parameter. When I send a post request to server it sends an OK response but does return PDF.

Comment: Go to the link and fill the following fields :
 
CIC/IC = Bimal Jukla, 
Type of File = Appeal,
Decision Type = Main,

and then click submit, pdf buttons will appear below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scrape the *filename* value from the hidden `<input>` field present in this [url](https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/view-decision?commissionname=302&file_category=1&fileno=&name=&public_authority=&decisiontypeid=1&frdate=&todate=&page_length=10&search_button=Submit).

Example *filename* value,

```
Q0lDLVBHSU1FLUEtMjAxOC02MTY5NjEtQkoucGRm
```

Now, you can send the *post* request to fetch the pdf file,

```
import requests
import base64

data = {
  'filename': 'Q0lDLVBHSU1FLUEtMjAxOC02MTY5NjEtQkoucGRm'
}

'''
To get the resultant file name you can either take the file name from
the `Content-disposition' key in the response headers or just base64
decode the filename value obtained from the hidden input field
'''
filename = base64.b64decode(data['filename'])

response = requests.post('https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/download', data=data)

# open the file to write in binary mode
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/YummyGhostwhiteTrigger)

Here is the curl request to download the PDF like in the above code.

```
curl 'https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/download' --data 'filename=Q0lDLVBHSU1FLUEtMjAxOC02MTY5NjEtQkoucGRm' -o $(base64 -d <<< Q0lDLVBHSU1FLUEtMjAxOC02MTY5NjEtQkoucGRm)
```

Comment: Also , can I use curl on it?

Comment: @nnd Yes, you can curl.

Comment: the response variable is returning a url which I can use in curl?

Comment: @nnd You cannot directly access the file url. You can only get the file by sending a POST request.

Comment: ok, I understand!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use selenium web drivers. You can try sending a post like the one bellow.

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
webdriver = Firefox()
response = webdriver.request('POST', 'url here', data={"param1": "value1"})
print(response)
```

Or you could try manually clicking them. Like

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get('https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/view-decision-all/1?opt=appCom&commissionname=302&file_category=1&fileno=&name=&public_authority=&decisiontypeid=1&frdate=&todate=&page_length=10&search_button=Submit')
driver.implicitly_wait(20) #because this site is slow.
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-primary').click()
```

The bottom did not work for me but I bet with some tinkering you could get one working. Cheers